# How to implement slideshow on AndEngine

Tags: java, android, memory-management, slideshow, andengine

I'd like to implement something like a slideshow on AndEngine. I need to show a big images(2000x800px). I'd like to have near 10 images but only 1 image can be displayed on the screen in one moment of time.

The main issue is memory management. I don't want to load all images in memory at once. I think the best idea is to load one image after the other(when the image is needed).

How to correctly load images in this way ? Also, how to correctly unload previous image from memory ?

Comment: First of all you have to consider some device restriction that they can not handle texture size greater than 1024px.

Comment: @Siddharth, yeah. I'll divide each image on two separate images 1024x1024px

Comment: That is best. You have to load all the images at a time because in application run if you load images and unload other images then it creates performance issue for your application.